# how to change background image every time page loads in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a set of images. I want this images to be back ground images to my home page. and every time homepage reloads a new background image should appear. I want to get it done in word-press. can anyone please tell me how i do that?

Comment: Pull all images urls inside `php` array, and use [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function with min and max limit to choose array index randomly! This will result random image on each page load.

Comment: is not there a free plugin to do that where I can upload set of images to it and then it provide me several options how image should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the **plugins**, which can be used but I'm not sure if they'll fulfill your needs but you can try these.

1. [Hot Random Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hot-random-image/)
2. [List of Plugins to Display Random Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/random-image/)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks it helped. i used mPress Image Refresh plugin mentioned in List of Plugins to Display Random Images